# Activity Diagram based on Use Case?

Tags: use-case

I need to learn how to map a use case diagram to an activity diagram.are you'll having any good examples or tutorials regarding this.

Thank you
have a nice day ahead
lahiru

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible because use case diagram describe your system by statically without dynamic, but activity diagram describe your system dynamically , sequential behavior.

Use Case Diagram : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Use_Case_Diagram

Activity Diagram : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activity_diagram

But you can map between two diagrams, your can use Sparx

link : http://www.sparxsystems.com/resources/map_uc.html

Comment: tx a lot for the answer. you mean that we are unable to model Use case to an Activity diagram is it ?

Comment: You can but you must fix manually dynamic aspect, it's impossible for system to define dynamic model based on static system, use cas just for enumerate your functionnalities, activity is for define sequential behavior of theses functionnalities

Comment: Happy to help you lahiruW